# How to create a top-footer and footer using foundation, just like foundation website

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, footer

I am new to CSS and fronted framework.

How to create a top-footer, subscription part  and footer using foundation, as similar as the one in foundation website.

I had tried the below using foundation css..

```
<div class="row full-width" id="subsc">
      <div class="large-4 columns">
        </div>
      <div class="large-8 columns">
        <div class="large-5 large-offset-6 columns">
        <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Label</label>
        <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="Inline Text Input">
        <a class="button" href=#>Get a Call back !</a>
        </div>
      </div>          
    </div>
```

Comment: <div class="row full-width" id="subsc">
          <div class="large-4 columns">
            </div>
          <div class="large-8 columns">
            <div class="large-5 large-offset-6 columns">
            <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Label</label>
            <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="Inline Text Input">
            <a class="button" href=#>Get a Call back !</a>
            </div>
          </div>          
        </div>

Comment: please post the code in your question so that everyone can see that to help you

Comment: sorry for forgetting to add the code snippet  ,below is the css other than the ones which comes with foundation css

.row.full-width {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#subsc{
 background-color: #085a78;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what is needed.

HTML

```
<footer>
    <div class="top">

    </div>
    <div class="center">

    </div>
    <div class="bottom">

    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
}

footer .top {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #085A78;
    min-height: 50px;
}

footer .center {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #074E68;
    min-height: 150px;
}

footer .bottom {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

*(colors copied from foundation)*
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arqpLp8j/4/)

Comment: that works but this in the middle of the page instead of being on the bottom of the page.

Comment: If your page has a scroll, please change **.footer** `position: absolute` to `position: relative` and place the footer division after the content ends/before closing the body tag